# How can I remove this case statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case

```
select id, shelfno, sectionno, 
       iif(tableA.shelfno = tableB.promono, itemdesc + ' Best Sale Right Now!', itemdesc),
       salesprice
from tableA
left join tableB on tableA.shelfno = tableB.promono
```

The query works as it is, however, I wonder if there's a better way of doing/writing this. I was thinking of using a outer apply, but it's not looking that would work.

EDIT: To be clearer, I'm trying to remove the IIF (same thing as CASE) from the SELECT statement.

Comment: In SQL Server 2012, IIF is the shorthand equivalent to CASE. I made the bad assumption that everyone would know that. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

No CASE, no IIF, as requested...

```
select id, shelfno, sectionno, 
       COALESCE(promodesc, itemdesc),
       salesprice
from tableA A
OUTER APPLY (
  SELECT
    itemdesc + ' Best Sale Right Now!' AS promodesc
  FROM tableA
  INNER JOIN tableB on tableA.shelfno = tableB.promono
  WHERE id = A.id
) B
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use CASE WHEN.

```
SELECT id
      ,shelfno
      ,sectionno
      ,itemdesc + CASE WHEN tableA.shelfno = tableB.promono 
                  THEN ' Best Sale Right Now!' 
                  ELSE '' END
      ,salesprice
FROM tableA
LEFT JOIN tableB 
ON tableA.shelfno = tableB.promono
```

Comment: My apologies. In SQL Server 2012, IIF is the shorthand equivalent to CASE. I made the bad assumption that everyone would know that. Sorry.

Comment: To be clearer, I'm trying to remove the IIF (same thing as CASE) from the SELECT statement.

Comment: You may want to change the way you concatenate by using `itemdesc + IIF(tableB.promono IS NULL, '', ' Best Sale Right Now!')` which seems to read a bit better IMO.. But I'm not sure of a way to remove the conditional.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
case 
    tableB.promono is null then itemdesc
    else itemdesc + ' Best Sale Right Now!'
end
```

Comment: Not quite. In SQL Server 2012, IIF is the shorthand equivalent to CASE. I made the bad assumption that everyone would know that. Sorry.

Comment: To be clearer, I'm trying to remove the IIF (same thing as CASE) from the SELECT statement.

Comment: you can't since your result is conditional

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that the left join is only being used in your `if` and no other columns are being used from `tableB` (which would be clearer if you aliased them all):-

```
SELECT id, shelfno, sectionno, itemdesc + CASE WHEN exists(
        select * 
        from tableB 
        where tableB.promono = tableA.shelfno) THEN ' Best Sale Right Now!'
    ELSE '' END as itemdesc,
    salesprice
FROM tableA
```

or in Sql Server 2012:-

```
SELECT id, shelfno, sectionno, itemdesc + iif(exists(
        select * 
        from tableB 
        where tableB.promono = tableA.shelfno),' Best Sale Right Now!','') as itemdesc,
    salesprice
FROM tableA
```

Comment: My apologies. In SQL Server 2012, IIF is the shorthand equivalent to CASE. I made the bad assumption that everyone would know that. Sorry.

Comment: To be clearer, I'm trying to remove the IIF (same thing as CASE) from the SELECT statement.

Comment: I don't understand why you are trying to avoid using `case`/`iif` when it appears to be the correct (most efficient) approach.  I don't see how 'cross apply' is going to produce a less expensive execution plan than the `exists()` that I've suggested (especially if the correct indexes exist to cover the query) - the optimizer will attempt to convert all the other suggested solutions to an `exists()` anyway...